# how to DISTINCT a multi tables query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.empno, E.ename,E.sal,E1.empno,E1.ename,E1.sal
FROM Emp E , Emp E1 WHERE E1.sal = E.sal AND
E.empno <> E1.empno  
Group by E.empno,E.ename,E.sal,E1.empno,E1.ename,E1.sal;
```

Even I use a DISTINCT I still got something like this

```
empno  ename  sal  empno  ename  sal  
1        a    123    2      b     123
2        b    123    1      a     123
```

And I only want to show it once...

Comment: That result is DISTINCT, it has no duplicate rows.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add the sample data as well, and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

First, use proper, explicit, `JOIN` syntax.

Second, the solution is simply to use `<`:

```
SELECT E.empno, E.ename, E.sal, E1.empno, E1.ename, E1.sal
FROM Emp E JOIN
     Emp E1 
     ON E1.sal = E.sal AND E.empno < E1.empno  ;
```

You might find it easier to just get the names and ids in one row, as in:

```
select e.sal, group_concat(e.empno order by e.empno) as empnos,
       group_concat(e.ename order by e.empno) as empnames
from emp e
group by e.sal
having count(*) > 1;
```